# Why is etherscan showing ERC223 tokens as ERC20

Tags: etherscan, erc-223

I created one token (ERC223) in `mainnet` using Remix and I tried to search that token address in `etherscan.io` but it's showing token type as ERC20.

Can you please explain why it shows up like this?

Comment: Can't put this as an answer, but ERC223 was deliberately designed with partial ERC20 backwards compatibility - in particular, blockchain explorers that support ERC20 don't need any changes to support ERC223.

Comment: probably because Etherscan doesn't support ERC223 tokens.